# How to remove grub bootloader from windows 10?

Tags: windows, grub2, boot-loader, gpt

I used to have ubuntu installed in pc hard disk but for other purposes, I can have only windows installed. Now I have uninstalled all partitions having ext4 fs, so only ntfs and bootable fs (vfat32 I think) remain. But still, when I boot I see grub bootloader (GNU GRUB version - `Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command , …`). Now I would like to remove this as well. I have tried to go to recovery mode, and from there to command prompt: `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` and then `bootrec.exe /fixboot` but `access denied` (I do not know why), but neither helped - I am still entering the grub. I do not have any media with full windows installation so I cannot boot from usb and make full install (I have tried although full restart which reinstalled the whole windows - still did not helped). So How can I delete/remove the grub bootloader from master boot record (or wherever it resides) to boot directly to windows?

PS: to get from the bootloader, I have to at least twice `exit` from the bootloader, when it finally boots windows. How to delete the bootloader?

Comment: You need to make sure Windows boot loader is default in UEFI. You should always have a Windows repair disk or installer with repair console. Also depends on whether grub is UEFI or BIOS & whether Windows is UEFI or BIOS and if system is set to boot in correct boot mode for install. If UEFI, you typically remove the UEFI boot entry and the /EFI/ubuntu or /EFI/grub or whatever Linux you had. But do not remove /EFI/Microsoft in ESP - efi system partition. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &

Comment: Here is my answer on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972762/10660507

Comment: Just follow the steps given in this stack overflow answer by me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972762/10660507

Answer (score 1):

- Under Windows you can remove GRUB using EasyUEFI or EasyBCD.
- Under Linux Live CD, e.g. SystemRescueCD you can do it using efibootmgr: https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows then first delete the partition where ubuntu is installed from disk management. For a detailed solution, Just follow the steps given in this stack overflow answer by me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972762/10660507